# Possibility to change info before saving user from facebook with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to implement a solution for logging in with the help of Passport.js, Node, MongoDB and AngularJS. I want to "interrupt" the process when the user presses "login with facebook/twitter/other", so that after the user details are returned from facebook/other, the user should be able to change some of them, amongst other their username before the user object is saved in the database (given that the username does not exist already). Where is the best place to interrupt this process? Is it a possiblity to redirect to a page and post an object from inside the main passport.js file?

Thanks alot!

Comment: why not put the user into the db as inactive and go on from there?

Comment: I would save the user to the db, then direct the user to a page where they can edit their details, and then update the db